# How can I get the height that sits above the waterline of a partly-submerged object?

Tags: buoyancy, volume, ice

If I know the density of water (say 1024 kg/m^3) and the density of ice (say 900 kg/m^3), and the volume of an object (say 8 x 10^9 m^3), how can I figure out how much of it is sitting above or below the waterline in metres?

It's easy to find what the float ratio is, but since most icebergs are wider below the surface I want to know if I can calculate a height, assuming the shape isn't extremely irregular.

Comment: You can compute the submerged volume...

Comment: You can't know the height without knowing the shape, but as @Ertxiem says you can know the volume below, and therefore the volume above.